# How do you switch the Raleigh RX10 rear light to flashing instead of constant

Tags: lighting

Sorry for the ludicrously specific question, but I just cannot work it out!

Mostly when I turn on my rear Raleigh RX10 USB rechargeable rear light it has a constant beam. Pressing the power button again toggles the intensity of the light. Pressing and holding the power button turns the light off (or back on). Occasionally it comes on flashing instead of constant, but I have no idea how. How can I reliably and predictably turn on flashing mode?

Comment: Please avoid the flashing mode. To other cyclists (and probably car drivers), riding behind you will become annoying as hell. The blinking might increase your visibility, but can be confusing and/or distracting, which might undermine your goal of improved safety.

Comment: Is avoiding a blinking mode standard advice?  Do biking organizations concur with this advice?

Comment: Interesting. I do find that with the front light. I only use blinking when I'm on well lit streets (it's less "annoying") and switch to constant for darker areas. It would be great to find a rear light with handlebar mounted controls.

Comment: @anderas: I like to use the "moving" lights mode for my tail-light, instead of flashing. The best way I can describe it is this: if there are 6 LEDs, at any given moment three of them are lit. The On lights keeps cycling back and forth. I don't find it as distracting as a blinking light, but it still attracts drivers' attention. But it would be great to see some sort of study on this.

Comment: I like that mode too, though to be clear the Raleigh RX10 rear light that this question is about does not offer that mode.

Comment: @Ben, good point. Have you considered converting this to a standalone question? I think it's worthwhile but I don't want to steal your idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical - no sooner posted than worked it out.

Pressing the button turns the light back on, but pressing and holding the button eventually turns it on in the mode it was not in last time (i.e. if it was on constant mode then pressing the button turns it back on in constant mode, but pressing and holding the button eventually turns it on in flashing mode.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I too couldn't work out how to get back into flashing mode, then did somehow, then couldn't get it back! You solution worked first time!